# Should we close questions as "unclear" when they quote dialogue that is not substantiated by evidence?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

[This recent question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/104645/deleted-scene-after-brett-is-killed-in-alien) asks about how a certain bit of dialog can be explained from the events of the movie, yet that piece of dialogue cannot be found when searching that movie's subtitles.

Shouldn't we close such questions, since they're based on badly remembered scenes and provide no evidence?

Case in point: [this question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/104619/why-is-jesse-looking-for-money-in-el-camino) (deleted, so only visible when you have enough points) was completely based on something the user made up himself and I eventually had to skim through the episode he references just to disprove his premise. The burden of proof for a question should be with the poster; I shouldn't need to waste time and effort on disproving it.

Comment: Uh...given I found the dialog in your example question in about 2 seconds in that transcript you quote (and have fixed the question accordingly), I'd say it's a bit "unclear" what "cannot be found when searching" actually means to begin with. So, while mistakes and false premises can happen, *maybe* we shouldn't immediately go for the close-vote button when we fail to remember the dialoge the same way the asker does. This seems to be a case-by-case problem.

Comment: But why would we allow badly remembered dialogue? In this day and age you can easily find the exact words for plenty of things online, or they could do a bit of effort and pull up the scene themselves and transcribe the words. Why should we do that effort? Stack Overflow requires you provide a ["Minimal, Reproducible Example"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), not a vague transcript of a memory of the code you're having trouble with.

Comment: Well, it also depends if the exact wording is relevant for the question. For example there's not much difference between "the son of a bitch is huge" and "it's really big" if what you're *actually* asking is how he knows it's big. If on the other hand you're asking about what a specific word means, it can be a bit more problematic if that word doesn't even exist in the dialogue. The purpose of the SO thing is to avoid code that's not actually exhibiting the problem that's asked about.

Comment: Yes, there are cases where the premise is just wrong and where it would be better to give the question some time to figure out what it's actually asking. I'd just want to avoid lumping them all together and close-voting a question because some dude forgot a random irrelevant word that doesn't change the question. It's not like we don't close enough questions here. We don't have to *excess* in "research".

Answer (score 4):

Like many things, this often depends on the specific case. Often enough it **isn't really relevant what the *specific* wording in the dialogue is**. For example in the question you cite as your first example I was able to find the quote the asker was referring to in literally 3-5 seconds in the transcript link you provided and fixed the question accordingly with the correct quote. It doesn't really matter if the guy said *"the son of a bitch is huge"* or *"it's really big"* for the question *how* he knew it was big in the first place.

It's not quite clear what "evidence" would be here. Should we always require a **link to a transcript to prove that that's really the exact dialogue? That seems quite excessive**. There's not always an exact transcript for every film available and I just don't consider it reasonable to expect every asker to actually bother seeking it out beforehand and linking to it if there is, especially when they've just seen the film and are quite certain what has been said.

Yes, it's a good idea to check and I personally tend to do that, especially since I rarely watch films in their original language. But making this a requirement would seem **too much of a burden when the exact words are not necessary for your question**, as in the example. And even when I check the transcript, I never link to it, since it is the primary work that's being discussed and **the film is an *implicit* source for the question/answer** anyway (consider also that even transcripts aren't always 100% correct). If you link to a transcript, fine. But I'd consider that courtesy, for an A+ mark. And if there is *no* transcript link, then what else is evidence? Is it "evidence" if the asker puts it into quote formatting?

But yes, there are also questions where this gets a bit more problematic, especially **when your entire question hinges on the exact wording of a phrase** (in which case it's also often tagged [dialogue](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dialogue), but not always and not vice versa). If it then turns out you just misheard the dialogue that can indeed get unpleasant for everyone involved and make the question end up a bit useless. In that case it **would be better to check the exact transcript or subtitles *if* available**. But we seem to be able to manage these. It's also unfortunate to close the question afterwards if it turned out to be based on a false premise, but maybe that's possible. It is a bit of a case-by-case decision.

What I would really want to avoid is people slapping the close-vote button just because someone misremembered a word or didn't include a transcript link, especially when the exact wording isn't relevant to the question. This seems to me a definition of "prior research" that is a bit *excessive*. And frankly, it's not like we don't close enough questions on this site. If anything I'd rather **people give questions the benefit of the doubt a little more than rushing to the close-vote button immediately, especially if improving the question is equally doable**, like I have shown in the linked example (like, you already *dug out* a transcript link, it might bother to do "others' work" for them, but we're ultimately doing it for the sake of the site. That's how collaborative editing works). If you're not in the mood for doing the asker's leg work, then you don't *have* to. But...it's also to a large degree what we're ultimately here to do.

Yes, your other example is the other side of the coin, where a user misremembered a scene. But...it also went the way of all mortal things by getting a bunch of downvotes and ultimately being deleted. And even *then* I wouldn't deem a proper answer that clarifies the asker's mistake to him beyond a possible alternative.

## So to a *blanket* statement on missing "transcript evidence" as a reason for closing I'd say no!

Comment: I find it kind of odd that you consider closing a question (or rather: putting it on hold) almost as some kind of punishment, whereas I've previously/elsewhere seen it described as a way to allow the user to improve it.

Comment: Maybe "offense" wasn't the best word. But I simply don't consider a misremembered irrelevant word reason enough to close a question, especially when editing is equally easy. Yes, a closed question can be reopened, but that's not a *zero* overhead task either and I wonder how many people who closed it would really bother to reopen-vote it, too. Closing is good when the question is so unclear that it really can't be answered, not when the dialgoue is *slightly* off or there isn't a transcript link available. Painting closing-editing-reopening as a 10 second process misses reality a little, too.

Comment: I don't consider closing a punishment (especially since that usually comes with moral undertones). But I *do* consider it a *halt* to answering the question, to be used when there is no point in engaging the question...yet. This can be changed and it happens, but not having that bump in the question's lifetime if not necessary (if e.g. it can be improved there and then or the defect isn't invalidating the question) would still be much preferable.